Iterm2 command history truncates long commands
When I try to apply my last command on iterm2, and that command is a bit longer than 1 line, the command history only saves part of the command, making the history feature useless to me.
How can I configure iterm2 to save the entire command I last executed, so I can use it again, despite its size?

Would you please give more detail?  What are you doing to apply your previous command from Iterm2's history display?  Are you performing a copy and paste of the lines that on the terminal window?

I am hitting the up arrow key on my keyboard and selectign the previous command and hitting enter.

It kinda looks like iterm2 adds an Enter character on long commands, when I copy them, they seem to break at the same character as the last one that was saved. So I need to manually ammend. This happens for all commands.

Why do you think the up arrow key is accessing the iTerm2 screen history and not the shell's command history?  Does it work differently when you're using the MacOS Terminal program?  Also, please edit your question to describe the steps you perform to "apply" the last command.

I have their integration installed, so I thought this would all be managed by iterm2. Does zsh truncates the history?
